# Why am I getting -1 for my row index?

Tags: jquery

I have the following table...

```
<table id="foo">
  <tr><td><!-- label --><!-- select --></td><tr>
  <tr><td><!-- label --><input type="text" /></td><tr>
  <tr><td><!-- label  --><!-- select --></td><tr>
  <tr><td><!-- label --><!-- radio buttons --></td><tr>
  <tr><td><!--hidden validation image--></td><tr>
</table>
```

Now when the page renders I hide all but the first row of my table using jQuery's .each. Now I wish to expand my script so that when a user causes a blur event on the textbox I retrieve that row's index and then show the next row, I'm using the following code for this:

```
$("#foo input[type=text]").blur(function() {
    alert($(this).closest("tr").index());
});
```

However the value alerted seems to be -1? So there's a problem there as it's not finding the row. Can someone tell me why I'm being so dumb?

Please note that I have no control of the table as this is determined by the back of the system (which I'm not allowed to touch!)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: You have no actual `input` tag in your HTML.

Comment: I haven't explained myself, for now I just want the index of thr row that contains the textbox that has been amended, I need to retain the index as I'll have to show the next row and when the user has no more rows to show I have to warn them to combine their values - but I'm not there yet. I just don't understand why the alert value is -1?

Comment: @Tomalak: then the event won't even fire :)

Comment: @naveen: Indeed, so there is a serious bug in the question.

Comment: jsfiddle slow as molasses at the most inconvenient time

Comment: It's probably worth posting the relevant section of the actual HTML, so we don't have to try to distinguish between problems with the HTML in the question and what you're actually working with.

Comment: @ Tomalak: i was wondering about the same thing (jsfiddle). maybe too much traffic from SO. maybe Jeff Atwood or Joel Spolsky could buy / support / fund it a bit... wishful thinking...

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be easier to read if I just put a comment where the form items would be - my bad! Sorry.

Comment: Can't understand three upvotes. There is no problem here.

Comment: It's still not working for me - I'm still getting -1. Something else must be interfering with the script?

Comment: @Mike Sav: Of course something else must be interfering with the script, or you are not showing us the whole code.

Comment: Howdy! This answered my problem - sorry to mess you around but the backend that creates the table spits all kinds of hidden unformatted inputs ('cos it's a rubbish CMS from years ago) thus the table I used as an example was different from the one being produced. I cleaned it up due to all the horrible generated GUIDs - thanks for all your help, sorry for being suck a dick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Maybe you are trying to achieve this?**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/gMuQE/)

If so, here is the appropriate code.

HTML:

```
<table id="foo">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$("#foo input[type=text]").blur(function() {
    alert($(this).closest("tr").index());
});
```

---

#### Edit

Your code is just fine. The problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: Howdy! This answered my problem - sorry to mess you around but the backend that creates the table spits all kinds of hidden unformatted inputs ('cos it's a rubbish CMS from years ago) thus the table I used as an example was different from the one being produced. I cleaned it up due to all the horrible generated GUIDs - thanks for all your help, sorry for being suck a dick!

Answer (score 0):

`$("#foo input[type=text]")` means that `this` is a text input in `#foo`. but according to your markup, there is no such element.

## Edit

Tested and it works: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73jaP/)

Answer (score 0):

> [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)
>
> Search for a given element from among the matched elements.
>
> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
> an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
> jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

So, your code should work.

[And, in fact, it does](http://jsfiddle.net/PHxB3/).

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine here. [See this test case.](http://cygal.info/tmp/test.html)